# Error in from's fields validation (Angular JS)

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a simple html form in which I have 3 fields.

Old Password

New Password

Retype password

But a strange behaviour is occuring that when I click and open that form, **New password** field is already red. I dont want it to be red till the user enters the data. Like I am doing for **Password Mismatch Validation** I have tried different things but I cant get why it is already red and submit button should stay disable if all fields are empty but its not working either.

[image]

This my form's code.

```
    <div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form class="form-horizontal" name="changepasswordform" id="changepasswordform">
            <fieldset> 
                <!--Old Password input-->
                <div class="form-group " ng-class="{'has-error': changepasswordform.OldPassword.$error.pattern}">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="OldPassword">Old Password*</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="OldPassword" id="OldPassword" placeholder="Old Password" ng-model="theChangePassword.OldPassword" ng-pattern="regex.Password">
                        <span ng-show="changepasswordform.OldPassword.$error.pattern && changepasswordform.OldPassword.$invalid"  class="help-block"> Please enter a valid password with at least 6 characters.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                   <!-- Password input-->
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': changepasswordform.password.$error.pattern || theChangePassword.NewPassword == theChangePassword.OldPassword}" >
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password"> New Password*</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="theChangePassword.NewPassword"  ng-pattern="regex.Password" ng-maxlength="20">
                        <span ng-show="changepasswordform.password.$error.pattern && changepasswordform.password.$invalid " class="help-block">Please enter a valid password with at least 6 characters. </span>
                         <span ng-show="theChangePassword.NewPassword == theChangePassword.OldPassword" class="help-block">password must be differ from old password.</span>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Password input-->
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error':  changepasswordform.confirmpassword.$error.pattern  || theChangePassword.NewPassword != theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword && (theChangePassword.NewPassword != '' && theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword != '' )}" >
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="confirmpassword">Retype Password*</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword"  ng-pattern="regex.Password" ng-maxlength="20" >
                    <span ng-show="theChangePassword.NewPassword != theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword && (theChangePassword.NewPassword != '' && theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword != '' )" class="help-block">Password mismatch</span>      
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Submit Button-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <button id="submit" ng-click="changepassword()" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="(theChangePassword.NewPassword != theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword ||  theChangePassword.NewPassword == theChangePassword.OldPassword && (theChangePassword.OldPassword == '' && theChangePassword.NewPassword == '' && theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword == ''))" >Submit</button>
                        <button id="submit" ng-click="cancelChangePassword()" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**After Updating : EDIT**
I updated my New Password div but still field field is red. Only difference is that message is not being displaying but field is red.

[image]

```
<!-- Password input-->
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': changepasswordform.password.$error.pattern || theChangePassword.NewPassword == theChangePassword.OldPassword}" >
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password"> New Password*</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="theChangePassword.NewPassword"  ng-pattern="regex.Password" ng-maxlength="20">
                    <span ng-show="changepasswordform.password.$error.pattern && changepasswordform.password.$invalid " class="help-block">Please enter a valid password with at least 6 characters. </span>
                      <span ng-show="(theChangePassword.NewPassword == theChangePassword.OldPassword) && changepasswordform.confirmpassword.$dirty && changepasswordform.password.$touched" class="help-block">password must be differ from old password.</span>  
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: check out my answer It will work .

Comment: the problem was in your condition .. updated the condition now fingers crossed

Comment: now it will work for sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
changepasswordform.matchingPassword.$dirty
```

It returns true if value the input has been changed . It is a good idea to use the `$dirty` keyword in put validation .

This checks only when the value has been changed . In below code I have added the key word to remove  the validation message till the input has been changed.

```
    <span ng-show="(theChangePassword.NewPassword == theChangePassword.OldPassword) && changepasswordform.confirmpassword.$dirty " class="help-block">password must be differ from old password.</span>
```

Since you want the `has-error` class after the value has been changed . Its a good keep the conditions simple

```
   <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error':  (changepasswordform.confirmpassword.$error.pattern  || (theChangePassword.NewPassword != theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword) && (theChangePassword.NewPassword != '' && theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword != '' )) && changepasswordform.matchingPassword.$dirty }" >
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="confirmpassword">Retype Password*</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword"  ng-pattern="regex.Password" ng-maxlength="20" >
                    <span ng-show="theChangePassword.NewPassword != theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword && (theChangePassword.NewPassword != '' && theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword != '' )  && changepasswordform.matchingPassword.$dirty" class="help-block">Password mismatch</span>      
                    </div>
                </div>
```

for the password div

```
<<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (changepasswordform.password.$error.pattern || (theChangePassword.NewPassword == theChangePassword.OldPassword) ) && changepasswordform.password.$dirty }" >
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password"> New Password*</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="theChangePassword.NewPassword"  ng-pattern="regex.Password" ng-maxlength="20">
                    <span ng-show="changepasswordform.password.$error.pattern && changepasswordform.password.$invalid && changepasswordform.password.$dirty  " class="help-block">Please enter a valid password with at least 6 characters. </span>
                     <span ng-show="(theChangePassword.NewPassword == theChangePassword.OldPassword) && changepasswordform.password.$dirty " class="help-block">password must be differ from old password.</span>  
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Not working! by adding this, validation message do not appears but field remains red when I open my form.

Comment: ng-class="{ 'has-error':  changepasswordform.confirmpassword.$error.pattern  || theChangePassword.NewPassword != theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword && (theChangePassword.NewPassword != '' && theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword != '' ) && changepasswordform.matchingPassword.$dirty }" add this as well . This should fix that issue as well .

Comment: I want to add this validation "Password must be differ" on new password not on confirm password.

Comment: I want to check new password against old password.

Comment: I have updated the answer .. @MikiJay ..  one hint should have been enough  this will work . here

Comment: Nop its not working still when I open the form Retype password field is red. :(

Comment: could you update what is not working @MikiJay give a screen shot

Comment: before you give screen shot try one for time with updated answer .. @MikiJay

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137328/discussion-between-boss-and-miki-jay).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a little more logic when displaying the error text.

By adding "**changepasswordform.password.$touched**" you ensure that the user has had some interaction with the form before you display the error.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.10"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <form class="form-horizontal" name="changepasswordform" id="changepasswordform">
        <fieldset>
          <!--Old Password input-->
          <div class="form-group " ng-class="{'has-error': changepasswordform.OldPassword.$error.pattern}">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="OldPassword">Old Password*</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="OldPassword" id="OldPassword" placeholder="Old Password" ng-model="theChangePassword.OldPassword" ng-pattern="regex.Password">
              <span ng-show="changepasswordform.OldPassword.$error.pattern && changepasswordform.OldPassword.$invalid" class="help-block"> Please enter a valid password with at least 6 characters.</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Password input-->
          <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': changepasswordform.password.$error.pattern || theChangePassword.NewPassword == theChangePassword.OldPassword}">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password"> New Password*</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="theChangePassword.NewPassword" ng-pattern="regex.Password" ng-maxlength="20">
              <span ng-show="changepasswordform.password.$error.pattern && changepasswordform.password.$invalid " class="help-block">Please enter a valid password with at least 6 characters. </span>
              <span ng-show="theChangePassword.NewPassword == theChangePassword.OldPassword && changepasswordform.password.$touched" class="help-block">password must be differ from old password.</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Password input-->
          <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error':  changepasswordform.confirmpassword.$error.pattern  || theChangePassword.NewPassword != theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword && (theChangePassword.NewPassword != '' && theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword != '' )}">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="confirmpassword">Retype Password*</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <input id="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword" ng-pattern="regex.Password" ng-maxlength="20">
              <span ng-show="theChangePassword.NewPassword != theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword && (theChangePassword.NewPassword != '' && theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword != '' )" class="help-block">Password mismatch</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Submit Button-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <button id="submit" ng-click="changepassword()" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="(theChangePassword.NewPassword != theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword ||  theChangePassword.NewPassword == theChangePassword.OldPassword && (theChangePassword.OldPassword == '' && theChangePassword.NewPassword == '' && theChangePassword.ConfirmPassword == ''))">Submit</button>
              <button id="submit" ng-click="cancelChangePassword()" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Plunk is working but not in my case. Field is still red when I open the form.

Comment: I am not sure what to say. Use text diff to see what is different in both the examples.